# SQL Login currently in use or not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logins

Recently we did a change on a client's production server. The change was to rename an sa login. Once we renamed the sa login we found out the client was having a problem because sa login was used in the connection string for a few applications which the client didn't mentioned to us. We were able to roll back the rename.

In the future, is there any way or query which we can execute so that we can know if sa login is currently used by any application or user before we renamed it or delete the login? Basically we want to check if any login is actively used by anyone before renaming or deleting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the below query to check in real time. Most applications will keep a session alive even when not in use.

```
SELECT 
    es.session_id,
    es.client_interface_name,
    es.login_name,
    es.nt_domain,
    es.nt_user_name,
    ec.client_net_address,
    ec.client_tcp_port,
    ec.local_net_address,
    ec.local_tcp_port
 FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions es
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec on es.session_id = ec.session_id
 WHERE login_name = 'Login Name'
```

Answer (score 2):

You run a server-side trace or Extended Event session to capture login activity.

I also would not have just renamed it in production. If you are referring to the `sa` account itself, disable it first to verify if anything breaks; and leave that disabled for a day or up to a week. How long you leave it is based on knowledge by the application owner. If they are not confident leave it disabled for at least a month.

If you are renaming just any old login to something else for a purpose, you obviously cannot go with the disable route. In that case you just have to let your trace run for a period of time to capture the activity.

One other option you might try is to just put in a server trigger that just writes an audit of login activity. There are a few examples of this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you're on 2008 you can set up an extended event session to record logins to a file (you can configure it to roll over and set a maximum size, even 64mb may be enough). You could use a ring buffer but it seems like a waste of memory... and if extended events were not possible then an audit trace will work, as will a standard trace (created in profiler and exported to a script). They can all do rollover and be accessed one way or another through simple repeatable T-SQL.

Have an agent job which reads the event file each day and aggregates data into a table (on the server or on another server - if you have a lot of servers it's good to consolidate, and you can do this in a bit of PowerShell but it becomes more complicated too).

The main columns you want are the login name, application name, database name, host name (though this can be spoofed), the date, whether it was successful or not, and aggregate a count.

I do this as standard across all the servers I look after because noticing a bunch of failed logins (security attack) or safely cleaning up the existing security over time is a core part of being a DBA.